# how to fetch image of per user from database full path name in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
<?php


                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                {
                    $no=$row['No'];
                    $path=$row['path'];
                    echo"<tr>";

                    echo"<td style=height:100px><img src=".$path."".$row["name"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["No"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["username"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["role"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["zone"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["designation"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["mobile2"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["email2"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$row["status"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td><A href='profile_pic.php?no=".$row["No"]."'>Attach Profile Pic</a></td>";

            ?>
                    <td>
                           <a href="JavaScript:newPopup('userentry.php?q1=<?php echo $no;?>');"><img src='../images/edit.png'></a>
                    </td>

            <?php 
                    echo"</tr>";
                }
?>
```

I am trying to fetch image of every user but image not shows. my path is stored in to database with file type trying to write path in variable also but isnt shows me a correct way or where iam wrong in this script. I will also shows my path where stored into db

Comment: if u can echo $path."".$row["name"] .. it should be http path

Comment: "<td><A href= replace this with "<td><a href=

Comment: try this one img tag closing missing and unneccesary concatenation   echo"<td style=height:100px><img src=".$path.$row['name']."></td>";

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/sjqs9ad2l/   Pathname stored in table    https://postimg.org/image/jzzy84n35/ o/p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace**

```
echo"<td style=height:100px><img src=".$path."".$row["name"]."</td>";
```

**to**

```
echo"<td style=height:100px><img src=".$path.$row['name']."></td>";
```

Comment: replace but not show image $path value with image name /var/www/po/Urmilaimages.jpg @shanu k k

Comment: @Black_Panthor - what is your $path?

Comment: $path value stores in to database with image name  https://postimg.org/image/sjqs9ad2l/

Comment: Your project name is 'po' na?and what is your image folder name?or it's directly upload to project folder without any sub folder?@Black_Panthor

Comment: directly upload into po folder no subfolder @Shanu k k

Comment: $path="/po/";                                                                                      echo"<td style=height:100px><img src=".$path.$row['name']."></td>"; try this @Black_Panthor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134544/discussion-between-shanu-k-k-and-black-panthor).

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any value in $row["No"]? Also file is present under the path mentioned in database? try to start image path from HTTP.

replace `profile_pic.php?no=".$row["No"]."` by the path starting from the domain or the localhost...

for testing you can use firebug in editing IMG path of href path.